# Determine current Mac Chrome web page using Python

Tags: python, macos, google-chrome

Is there a way to determine programmatically, using Python, which web page is currently active in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet, it seems.  Such tasks are done, with other browsers, via the Applescript interface, but, as [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27468) shows, while hotly requested for Chrome on the Mac this feature is not there yet.

(Once a Mac app does get a good Applescript interface, there are several ways to use that interface from Python, without needing to actually involve Applescript as a language -- this has been touched upon on other SO questions about other apps -- but the problem is that Chrome in particular doesn't yet support this quintessentially Mac-ish functionality).

Given the insistence of the request I'd expect somebody to eventually roll up their sleeves and contribute a patch for the purpose, but it doesn't seem to have occurred yet.

Comment: Thanks for putting the question to rest. Hopefully the patch will pop up someday soon.

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome for Mac has added the AppleScripting method for getting the URL.

### Here's the Chromium AppleScript SDK

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/design-documents/applescript

### Example from the page linked below:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
   get URL of active tab of window 1
end tell
```

### More examples here:

http://laclefyoshi.blogspot.com/2010/10/google-chrome-ver.html